# How to use typedef with unordered_map::const_iterator?

Tags: c++, typedef

I have a class that uses `unordered_map` container and custom templates.

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class List {
}
```

In that class I have defined a new `unordered_map::const_iterator` with `typedef` as follow:

```
typename typedef std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator ListIterator;
```

Note that I have created that type to use it as a function parameter as follow:

```
void Remove(List<KeyType, ValueType>::ListIterator from, List<KeyType, ValueType>::ListIterator to) {}
```

The problem is that there is an error occurs when compiling `Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'ListIterator'`.
Why That error occurs, what's wrong in my typedef?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the order of `typename` and `typedef` reversed. Change the declaration to

```
typedef typename std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator ListIterator;
```

Or apply [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) (since C++11) which looks more clear.

```
using ListIterator = typename std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried the two ways but the same error message still appears. the error message points to the "Remove" method.

Comment: @LionKing I tried it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PIYBclgBOqt0pKze) and works, I suppose `Remove` is a member function, is it?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why that is still happening, I am using "Visual Studio 2015" perhaps it is the cause?

Comment: @LionKing I got it. You need to add `typename` as `void Remove(typename List<KeyType, ValueType>::ListIterator from, typename List<KeyType, ValueType>::ListIterator to) {}`, or just `void Remove(ListIterator from, ListIterator to) {}`. [LIVE](https://rextester.com/VQW14582). Anyway it seems to be MSVS's issue.

Comment: I found it, the "typedef" was declared after the "Remove" method, so the "Remove" method did not see the "typedef" declaration.

Comment: I have an inquiry about how important is the definition of `typename` keyword firstly "ex: `typedef typename std::unordered_map......` why not `typedef std::unordered_map.....` " without `typename`?

Comment: @LionKing Because `std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator` is a dependent name which depends on the template parameter `KeyType` and `ValueType`, then `typename` is required. See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3309790).